# Pointers, dynamic variables, C++

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, dynamic

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s83bu.png) 
I keep receiving errors when running this program. What do these errors mean? A screenshot is attached. 
This is the problem:

A class Area that has two private variable members; units of type string and area_value of type float.

1) Input from the keyboard the area_value and its units. Compute one-half and one-quarter of the area and display the results with unit.
2) Destroy the dynamic variable at the end.

```
#include <iostream
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Area
{
    public:
    Area();
    void setu(string a);
    void seta(float b);
    string getu();
    float geta();
private:
    string unit;
    float area_value;
};

int main()
{

Area *p = new Area();
string a;
float f;
cout << "Enter a unit with no space: ";
getline(cin, a);
p->setu(a);
cout << "Enter a value of area: ";
cin >> f;
p->seta(f);
cout << "A half of your input = " << f / 2 << endl;
cout << "A quarter of your input = " << f / 4 << endl; 
delete p;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the error messages here instead of the link to an image.

Comment: You should meaningfully initialize your objects. What's the point of an `Area` that has neither units nor the area initialized?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

1. You have not implemented the member functions, or
2. You have implemented the member functions in a separate file and forgot to include it in building the executable.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forgot to implement the constructor Area() and the methods of your Area class.

Answer (score 0):

The first include is missing greater than sign (>). The public Area class only defines the functions, not implementing them. Variable p is defined as a pointer.

You can also add half and quarter as functions. I modified it slightly so it compiles with clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 -o area area.cpp.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Area {
public:
    Area() {};
    ~Area() {};
    void setu(string u) { unit = u; }
    void seta(float a) { area_value = a; }
    string getu() { return unit; }
    float geta() { return area_value; }
    float getHalf() { return area_value / 2; }
    float getQuarter() { return area_value / 4; }
private:
    string unit;
    float area_value;
};

int main() {
    Area p {};
    string a;
    float f;
    cout << "Enter a unit with no space: ";
    getline(cin, a);
    p.setu(a);
    cout << "Enter a value of area: ";
    cin >> f;
    p.seta(f);
    cout << "A half of your input = " << p.getHalf() << endl;
    cout << "A quarter of your input = " << p.getQuarter() << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```